# Running brew generates warnings

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, homebrew

I installed the latest Homebrew on OS X 10.6.5
Running any command generates this warning:

> /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:34: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777

Why I'm getting this warning? and how to remedy?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First, there are two brew commands that are helpful when debugging problems.  They are:

```
$ brew doctor
$ brew missing
```

Second, Homebrew is telling you that `/usr/local/bin` is set to be too permissive in who can write to that directory -- a potential security problem.  To remedy this, you can reset your permissions back to what Homebrew intended.

```
$ chmod 755 /usr/local/bin
```

If you get an error while trying to do this, it may mean that your /usr/local directory (and subdirectories) are owned by the wrong user.  If that's the case, I would consider deleting your /usr/local directory and [reinstalling Homebrew *correctly*](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/README.md).  Alternatively, you can override the error by prefixing the last command with sudo and entering your admin password:

```
$ sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: I agree with Asmus that deleting `/usr/local` is a bad recommendation.

Comment: When you first start with Homebrew, you need to start with a clean `/usr/local`.  The fact that the permissions in `/usr/local` were not set correctly is a sign that Homebrew was installed incorrectly in the first place.  Starting from scratch is not a bad thing in this scenario.

Answer (score 88):

I had the same problem and just fixed it with these 3 commands, roughly taken from Homebrew installation script:

```
sudo chgrp -R admin /usr/local
sudo chmod -R g+rwx /usr/local
sudo chmod -R o-w /usr/local
```

Comment: Helped me too when some other program (Airfoil's InstantOn) messed up the permissions. In addition to that I had to clean the git repo living in `/usr/local` by running `cd /usr/local && git reset --hard && git clean -d -f`

Answer (score 7):

This is a security feature of ruby, you can change permissions on the directory /usr/local/bin to get rid of this by running:

```
sudo chmod go-w /usr/local/bin
```

and entering your password on the prompt.

You do **not** need to change ownership and **neither** should delete /usr/local as Ryan suggested (that would require you to rebuild everything you´ve accomplished so far), the directory is owned by root and this is the usual way.

Comment: With Homebrew, the `/usr/local` directory is **not** to be owned by root. That's the whole point.  Starting from scratch is not a bad thing in this scenario, because it's evident that the Homebrew install was already botched somehow or by something.  In other words, it's very likely that other variables (such as misplaced libs) are in place that will cause further pain down the road.

Comment: Homebrew is not the only thing residing in /usr/local/, if you were to install e.g. MacTex, more than a gigabyte of TeXLife packages would go there and you surely do not want to re-install them just because Homebrew doesn´t  work. However compelling Homebrews idea of owning /usr/local yourself might sound, I prefer the usual way: system-wide available applications are owned by root.